# How should one phrase validation error messages?

Tags: error-message, validation, wording, errors

What is the best phrase to use **considering that these are short error messages** that is positioned **right beside the labels / input they are referring to**. For example, there's a missing email address, what is the best way to tell the user? (I omitted the label as it's redundant considering that it's already beside the label.)

1. **Tell them what to do:** "Enter a value."
2. **Tell them what's wrong:** "This cannot be left blank." OR "This field is missing."

Which of the 2 is the best approach? I'm aware that combining these two are good for general error messages (usually at the top of the form or where there's sufficient space). But if you only have little space (just one-line), which is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use those format:

> *Fieldname* cant be empty

or

> Please complete *fieldname*

or

> Please enter a valid *fieldname*

You can study in deep error messages here:

- [Inline validation in web form](http://alistapart.com/article/inline-validation-in-web-forms)
- [Handling User Error with Care](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/showing-error-messages-to-users/)

Comment: I would phrase the first in a positive manner: "_Fieldname_ should have a value" Phrases with "not"s (and his friends) can become confusing very quickly, especially when combined with "or" and/or "and".

Comment: Yes, I think too positive manners are more clear.